# What is the synonym of "spy"?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I know the word "watch" is used as a synonym of spy. Are there other synonyms that are used by native speakers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the word "**snoop**" could be a good synonym.

> *I caught him **snooping around** in my office.*
>
> *Reporters were **snooping on** the celebrities*

Answer (score 4):

You can also use "notice", "observe", "monitor", "track", "keep an eye on", "keep track of", "keep tabs on" -- all these have slightly different meanings, depending on what you mean to convey when you'd use *spy*.

- Use *notice* if you mean to say that you suddenly noticed a detail of some sort.
- Use *observe* if you mean to say that you're dispassionately watching something unfold, or noticing a detail or series of details with emotional detachment.
- Use *monitor* if you mean to say that you're continually watching something with some measurement in mind that would prompt you to step in or take action if the measurement goes outside a certain range.
- All of the *keep...* phrases are informal ways of saying that you're going to spend some casual effort going forward to (essentially) monitor something -- they're mostly casual ways of using the *monitor* sense of *spy*.

Notice that, strictly speaking, *spy* can carry a connotation of secret, covert behaviour. When you *spy* you have an *agenda* of some sort, or a secret purpose. The most neutral version of *spy* is to suddenly notice something: the longer the activity spent observing, the more you convey a sense of secretness.

Answer (score 1):

To *spy*, in the sense of watching someone or something, could also mean keeping that thing under surveillance.

In that sense, *spy* (the verb) has approximately the same meaning as *[surveil](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/surveil)*.

Comment: Is that formal? Can I use it informally?

Comment: _Surveil_ is not formal, but it's not commonly used, either.

Comment: Not formal? Meaning what exactly?

Comment: *Surveillance* and *reconnoiter* are both specialised terms associated with government/military action; *case* (as in "I cased the joint" -now quite archaic) equally implies some formal, quasi-legitimate undertaking. You can use them all informally, but you should know they have those associations.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean *to spy* then you can use *snoop* (informal), *keep under surveillance/observation*, *keep a watch on*, *keep an eye on*, *observe*, *spot*.
If you mean *spy* used as noun, then you can use *secret agent*, *undercover agent*, *intelligence agent*, *double agent*, *mole*, *snoop*.

Which word/phrase suits better depends on the context.

Comment: "intelligence agent", not "intelligent agent".  Not bad enough to warrant a -1, though.

Comment: Whoops… It seems I made it rhyme with _agent_.

Answer (score 1):

***infiltrator, undercover agent***

Answer (score 1):

This depends on context and connotation.
There are spies-heroes and there are sneaks, sneakers, snitches, informers, finks, noses, squeakeres, denunciators, questmans, talebearers, whistlers, grass, nark, noser, stool pigeon, checker, squeal, zuch, rat, rounder, delator, etc.

Seems like negative characters are always have better and more specific characteristic terms than positive ones.